# Completion doesn't work "properly" when it is aliased

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, alias

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with bash v4.3.46.

I set an alias "p" to "python3". By writing this in `.bashrc`

```
alias p='python3'
```

**Problem:**

Completion doesn't work properly when aliased. (It shows in-executable files for python, too)

```
$p <tab>
a.py   a.txt  b.py   b.txt  c.txt  hoge/
```

Compared with normal command: (This only shows executable files)

```
$python3 <tab>
a.py  b.py  hoge/
```

**What I tried:**

When I checked the completion for `python3`,

```
$complete -p python3
complete -F _python python3
```

Therefore, I added the following in `.bashrc`

```
complete -F _python p
```

And now, I got:

```
$complete -p p
complete -F _python p
```

It seems to be working, however, I got the same result as the beginning.

------- Added --------
I found the definition of _python at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/python3`

```
# bash completion for python                               -*- shell-script -*-

_python_modules()
{
    COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -W "$( ${1:-python} -c 'import pkgutil
for mod in pkgutil.iter_modules(): print(mod[1])' )" 2>/dev/null -- "$cur" ) )
}

_python()
{
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

    case $prev in
        -'?'|-h|--help|-V|--version|-c)
            return 0
            ;;
        -m)
            _python_modules "$1"
            return 0
            ;;
        -Q)
            COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "old new warn warnall" -- "$cur" ) )
            return 0
            ;;
        -W)
            COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "ignore default all module once error" \
                -- "$cur" ) )
            return 0
            ;;
        !(?(*/)python*([0-9.])|-?))
            [[ $cword -lt 2 || ${words[cword-2]} != -@(Q|W) ]] \
                && _filedir
            ;;
    esac


    # if '-c' is already given, complete all kind of files.
    local i
    for (( i=0; i < ${#words[@]}-1; i++ )); do
        if [[ ${words[i]} == -c ]]; then
            _filedir
        fi
    done


    if [[ "$cur" != -* ]]; then
        _filedir 'py?([co])'
    else
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$( _parse_help "$1" -h )' -- "$cur" ) )
    fi

    return 0
} &&
complete -F _python python python2 python3

# ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
```

editing this seems to be fine.

- Could you tell me how shoud I edit this?
- To edit this, I need sudo, is there any other way that doesn't use sudo?
  Thank you.

Comment: mind pasting the definition of the function `_python()`?

Comment: I looked for 
`/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`
 and
`/etc/bash_completion`
however, I couldn't find where `_python()` is written.
Does anyone know where it is?
I didn't write it by myself, so it should be in the original place.

Comment: From what I can tell the issue is within the definition of that `_python` script; it's assuming the name of the invoking command to have the name `python`, or `python[0-9]` when it checks the last word on the command line, and because the alias doesn't match that it fails to return the python specific options.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.
Finally, I found the file.
I'm gonna edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this case statement: `!(?(*/)python*([0-9.])|-?))` is restricting the tab completion to only aliases/commands that have the word `python` in them.

If you change that case statement to be: `!(*|-h))` or even `!(p|-h))` then your autocomplete should work.

I would personally just add the modified code to my `.bashrc`... something like the following, just renaming the functions and doing the aliasing:

```
# bash completion for python                               -*- shell-script -*-

_python_modules_cust()
{
    COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -W "$( ${1:-python} -c 'import pkgutil
for mod in pkgutil.iter_modules(): print(mod[1])' )" 2>/dev/null -- "$cur" ) )
}

_python_cust()
{
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

    case $prev in
        -'?'|-h|--help|-V|--version|-c)
            return 0
            ;;
        -m)
            _python_modules_cust "$1"
            return 0
            ;;
        -Q)
            COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "old new warn warnall" -- "$cur" ) )
            return 0
            ;;
        -W)
            COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "ignore default all module once error" \
                -- "$cur" ) )
            return 0
            ;;
        !(*|-?))
            [[ $cword -lt 2 || ${words[cword-2]} != -@(Q|W) ]] \
                && _filedir
            ;;
    esac


    # if '-c' is already given, complete all kind of files.
    local i
    for (( i=0; i < ${#words[@]}-1; i++ )); do
        if [[ ${words[i]} == -c ]]; then
            _filedir
        fi
    done


    if [[ "$cur" != -* ]]; then
        _filedir 'py?([co])'
    else
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$( _parse_help "$1" -h )' -- "$cur" ) )
    fi

    return 0
} &&
alias p='python3' &&
complete -F _python_cust p

# ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
```